# Auto formatting in VIM for PHP

Tags: php, vim, autoformatting

I want to be able to take the following code

```
if ($something)
{
   do something
}
```

and make it

```
if ($somthing) {
    do something
}
```

through out a whole file without really going to each statement and correcting it. I am not a regex guru so any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Use PEAR's [PHP_Beautifier](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier) to reformat your code.

Comment: +1 for the link. Consider giving an example of how to use it.

Comment: There is a button "documentation". Follow that. In the tree, there is a "how to use" entry.

Comment: I installed it, ran it, but it seems that it doesnt save the file again after formatting, which means one would have to rename every file again, which is kinda defeating the purpose i wanted. I was hoping actually for a vim plugin, or regex script or something :(

Comment: You can set the `--output` parameter to the same as the `--input` parameter, so it gets overwritten.

Comment: i think there is a bug somewhere, if i use the same file for input and output, it throws errors and wipes the file clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Search for a line that contains `if` but doesn't end in `{`:

   ```
   /if [^{]*$
   ```
2. Join this line with the next one:

   ```
   J
   ```

You can map this sequence to something:

```
nmap <F2> /if[^{]*$<CR>J
```

so that every <kbd>F2</kbd> press will change the next if instance (<kbd>100</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> will change 100 instances and so on).